# Save Images to folder located in wwwroot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a folder in wwwroot folder named Images. I want to save my images to that folder. Right now the images are being saved in the wwwroot folder (outside Images), and the name of the image saved starts with Images. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
  string filepath = Path.Combine(_caminho.WebRootPath, "Images" + name);
```

"name" ia a string that has the name of the image. Why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like "Images" is being prepended to the name. Without seeing more of the code, I have to assume you should be doing this instead: `string filepath = Path.Combine(_caminho.WebRootPath, "Images", name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're concatenating the string `"Images"` to `name`. I would suggest that you do

```
(..."Images", name);
```